# Image load fail using Picasso,Glide,Image Loader ,Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, android-asynctask, picasso, android-glide, universal-image-loader

> i have creating Hindi video song application, but video thumb can't display in video list.
>   (Single image are loaded but multiple image array can't load.)

**using multiple image loader library but doesn't load image:**

[image]

> Glide:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'


Glide .with(viewHolder.icon_1.getContext())
            .load(((AppModelicon) this.b.get(i)).getThumnail())
            .into(viewHolder.icon_1)  ;

Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load("https://img.youtube.com/vi/EEX_XM6SxmY/mqdefault.jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    // log exception
                    Log.e("TAG", "Error loading image", e);
                    return false; // important to return false so the error placeholder can be placed
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(viewHolder.icon_1);
```

> Picasso:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.+'

Picasso.get()
            .load("https://img.youtube.com/vi/EEX_XM6SxmY/mqdefault.jpg")
            .resize(50, 50)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(viewHolder.icon_1);
```

> using request manager with glide :

```
RequestManager requestManager = Glide.with(a)
            .applyDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .applyDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera));
                requestManager
            .applyDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true));
                requestManager.load(pathToFile)
            .into(viewHolder.icon_1);
```

> background task method use :

```
String pathToFile = this.b.get(i).getThumnail();
DownloadImageWithURLTask downloadTask = new DownloadImageWithURLTask(viewHolder.icon_1);
downloadTask.execute(pathToFile);

public class DownloadImageWithURLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageWithURLTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String pathToFile = urls[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(pathToFile).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

> Please help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you please share screenshot if possible & also where is your music and image hosted?

Comment: @VinayJayaram  please check image.

Comment: have you tried some other images(maybe imgur)? or do you have internet permission?

Comment: @Wesely   other image working and  i also giving internet permission.

Comment: @AshishVirani where are the images hosted?

Comment: @VinayJayaram  youtube video.

Comment: what is error in onLoadFailed?

Comment: @Nik Error:com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource

Comment: @AshishVirani I am able to load url as you given in your question. check my answer. One Question is your imageview is not null right?

Comment: Bala bala shaitan ka saala:)).

Comment: @Nik you right  but on activity single image are loaded but inside adapter multiple image doesn't load.

Answer (score 3):

If you are load image in recyclerview, below code might help you out.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    Glide.with(this.context)
            .load(urls.get(position))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(holder.getImage());
}
```

for more full tutorial you can visit https://ledron.github.io/RecyclerView/

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass MainActivity.this as context its always wrong..

try this

```
//in activity
Glide.with(this) 
       .load("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1123379185764917248/On9ZnfVh.png")
       .into(imageView)

//in Fragments
Glide.with(view.context)
  .load("url")
  .into(imageView)
```

replace .load("url") and "imageView" with your own.

Answer (score 0):

remove the below line in dependency

annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'

Answer (score 0):

I am able to load your image url using glide:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

Glide.with(this@MainActivity)
                .load("https://img.youtube.com/vi/EEX_XM6SxmY/mqdefault.jpg")
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(imageView)
```

Comment: on activity single image are loaded but inside adapter multiple image doesn't load.

Comment: is your view holder and image view are not null right?

Comment: Pass activity context instead of viewholder imageview context in Glide in your adapter

Comment: try to add static url in adapter. check for context and imageview is not null in your Glide inside adapter and it should be inside onBindViewHolder

Comment: static image url is working,  but load image url using arraylist is not working.

Comment: Then it is problem with your arraylist thumbnai..Not is any libray issue.. What is value in ((AppModelicon) this.b.get(i)).getThumnail()?

Comment: b.get(i)).getThumnail() is perfect.

Comment: then try with ((AppModelicon) this.b.get(i)).getThumnail().toString() or Uri.parse(((AppModelicon) this.b.get(i)).getThumnail().toString())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203302/discussion-between-nik-and-ashish-virani).